# How to filter data from controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to filter data from controller

```
$scope.aciveresults = data ;  // data -- getting  from service
```

i have tried

```
$scope.aciveresults = $filter( data | data.status == true ) ;
```

But it throwing error .

I want to show the data only have status true and want to do in controller itslef .

Please suggest

Comment: Don't you need a double equal sign int the filter? ==

Comment: i tried with that also ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to use filter in javascript do it this way

```
$scope.aciveresults = $filter('filter')(data, {status: true}, [true/false for strict mode])
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Answer (score 2):

- Inject $filter to your controller
- Then wherever you want to use filter,

  `$filter('filtername');`

In your case you have to use the built-in filter **filter** .

`$filter('filter')($scope.aciveresults,{status:true})`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sb_satchitanand/B7BZ5/)

OR you can also invoke the filter by filter name plus the Filter suffix. 
So,

```
function MyCtrl($scope,filterFilter){
   filterFilter($scope.aciveresults,{status:true})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably do this in your ng-repeat, like so:

```
 ng-repeat="items in data | filter:item.status == true"
```

since, most probably, data.status doesn't exist, data is a set of objects, each having a status key / value pair.

Comment: thanks , but i know this method , i need to do in controller itself , I have to change the status on click i cannot repeat the html

Comment: If you can avoid that kind of filters in DOM, better do it in controller

Answer (score 0):

```
var resultArray = $filter('filter')($scope.aciveresults , {status:true} );
```

**syntax:** `$filter('filter')(array, expression, comparator)`

Check angular docs for more filter operations